# Node.js pass a value to a partial view

Tags: node.js, express, partial-views

I have a route that looks like this:

```
app.get('/Search', function (req, res) {
    var searchString = req.query.SearchString;
    var request = require('./cstapi')(searchString, onBody);
    function onBody(body) {
    res.render('index', { output: body });
    }
});
```

and an index.ejs that looks like this:

```
<div id="searchDiv">
    <% include ../partials/search %>
    <br>
    <% include ../partials/results %>
</div>
```

search looks like this:

```
<form action="./search" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="SearchString" class="form-control" >
    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="form-control">
</form>
```

and results looks like this:

```
<p>Search returned the following: <%= output %></p>
```

I'm trying to get the search results to display in a partial view after the user submits the form. With the above I get `output is not defined` when attempting to render index and the subsequent partial views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around although I'm not 100% sure this is the best way of doing it:

By adding 'null check' to output in index I can avoid the `output not defined` error when accessing the results partial without search results.

So index now becomes:

```
<div id="searchDiv">
    <% include ../partials/search %>
    <br>
    <%if (typeof output !== 'undefined') { %>
     %> <% include ../partials/results %>
     <% } %>
</div>
```

Hopefully someone can provide a better way?